# CVS Tagging recursively from within a shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

My team uses CVS for revision control.I need to develop a shell script which extracts the content from a file and does a CVS tag  to all .txt files(also the text files present in the sub-directories of the current direcotry) with that content. The file from which the content is extracted ,the script ,both are present in the same directory.

I tried running the script :

```
#!bin/bash
return_content(){
  content=$(cat file1)
  echo $content
}
find . -name "*.txt" -type f -print0|grep - v CVS|xargs -0 cvs tag $content
```

file1=> the file from where the content is extracted
"abc"=> content inside file1

Output:

```
abc
find: paths must precede expression
Usage: find [path...] [expression]
cvs tag: in directory
cvs [tag aborted]: there is no version here; run 'cvs checkout' first
```

I cannot figure out the problem. Please help

Comment: Why aren't you tagging **ALL** files in your revision with that tag? Is this being executed in a CVS working directory?

Comment: yes its ina Cvs directory..ant the requirement is such that it should only tag the txt file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few problems with the script.

1)  The shebang line is missing the root /.
You have `#!bin/bash` and it should be `#!/bin/bash`

2)  the `-v` option to grep has a space between the - and the v (and it shouldn't)

3)  You don't actually call the return_content function in the last line - you refer to a variable inside the function.  Perhaps the last line should look like:

```
find . -name "*.txt" -type f -print0|grep -v CVS|\
    xargs -0 cvs tag $( return_content )
```

4) even after fixing all that, you may find that the grep complains because the print0 is passing it binary data (there are embedded nulls due to the -print0), and grep is expecting text.  You can use more arguments to the find command to perform the function of the grep command and cut grep out, like this:

```
find . -type d -name CVS -prune -o -type f -name "*.txt" -print0 |\
    xargs -0 cvs tag $( return_content )
```

find will recurse through all the entries in the current directory (and below), discarding anything that is a directory named CVS or below, and of the rest it will choose only files named *.txt.

I tested my version of that line with:

```
find . -type d -name CVS -prune -o -type f -name "*.txt" -print0 |\
 xargs -t -0 echo ls -la
```

I created a couple of files with spaces in the names and .txt extensions in the directory so the script would show results:

```
bjb@spidy:~/junk/find$ find . -type d -name CVS -prune -o \
-type f -name "*.txt" -print0 | xargs -t -0 ls -la 
ls -la ./one two.txt ./three four.txt 
-rw-r--r-- 1 bjb bjb 0 Jun 27 00:44 ./one two.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 bjb bjb 0 Jun 27 00:45 ./three four.txt
bjb@spidy:~/junk/find$
```

The -t argument makes xargs show the command it is about to run.  I used `ls -la` instead of `cvs tag` - it should work similarly for cvs.

Comment: Yes this works !! I was actually making the mistake in the last time!! thank you for the detailed reply